# OCR: weighted Levenshtein distance

Tags: ocr, metrics, levenshtein-distance

I'm trying to create an optical character recognition system with the dictionary.

In fact I don't have an implemented dictionary yet=)

I've heard that there are simple metrics based on Levenstein distance which take in account different distance between different symbols. E.g. 'N' and 'H' are very close to each other and d("THEATRE", "TNEATRE") should be less than d("THEATRE", "TOEATRE") which is impossible using basic Levenstein distance.

Could you help me locating such metric, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance (and kindly some working code is included in the link)

**Update:**

http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/edit-distance-1.html

Comment: Unfortunately it's not what I was looking for. Anyway I'm already graduated with honors - and I don't need a solution anymore=)

Comment: That's odd, because it's purpose is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: hmmm.. I've looked through your link. But what I've understood is that they just added one more operation: transposition. Where transposition is when you change two neighboring symbols. If I'm wrong could you please specify the place on the wiki page where they are talking about different distance between different letters?

Comment: Sorry I'de been looking at a lot of links that day, the second one needs to be taken in conjunction.

Answer (score 4):

A few years too late but the following python package (with which I am NOT affiliated) allows for arbitrary weighting of all the Levenshtein edit operations and ASCII character mappings etc.

https://github.com/infoscout/weighted-levenshtein

```
pip install weighted-levenshtein
```

Also this one (also not affiliated):

```
https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity
```

Comment: Does it require you to create the full weight matrix? Does anyone know if there's any reasonable weight matrix out there for basic ascii characters for example? Doesn't need to be perfect, but basically have lower weight for things such as [o O 0] or [i l 1], and higher for things such as [o x].

Comment: You need to populate each element of the matrix with _something_, even some default value. Your examples are OCR-specific; keyboard-inputted elements would be different. The problem is one needs ground-truth data, i.e. labelled data, which is labour-intensive, so companies are reluctant to share. reCAPTCHA is an example.

Comment: Well there are plenty of open source resources, such as Tesseract, which is an entirely open source OCR engine with trained data. It even has a list of ambiguous characters:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/blob/master/eng/eng.unicharambigs

Still, since OCR is so widely done, I'm still surprised something like this doesn't exist in the OSS community.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently created a python package that does exactly that https://github.com/zas97/ocr_weighted_levenshtein.

In my Weigthed-Levenshtein implementation the distance between "THEATRE" and "TNEATRE" is 1.3 while the distance between "THEATRE" and "TOEATRE" is 1.42.

Other exemples are the d("O", "0") is 0.06 and d("e","c") is 0.57.

This distances have been calculated by running multiple ocrs in a synthetic dataset and doing statistics on the most common ocr errors. I hope it helps someone =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (C#) where weight of "replace character" operation depends on distance between character codes:

```
      static double WeightedLevenshtein(string b1, string b2) {
        b1 = b1.ToUpper();
        b2 = b2.ToUpper();

        double[,] matrix = new double[b1.Length + 1, b2.Length + 1];

        for (int i = 1; i <= b1.Length; i++) {
            matrix[i, 0] = i;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= b2.Length; i++) {
            matrix[0, i] = i;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= b1.Length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= b2.Length; j++) {
                double distance_replace = matrix[(i - 1), (j - 1)];
                if (b1[i - 1] != b2[j - 1]) {
                    // Cost of replace
                    distance_replace += Math.Abs((float)(b1[i - 1]) - b2[j - 1]) / ('Z'-'A');
                }

                // Cost of remove = 1 
                double distance_remove = matrix[(i - 1), j] + 1;
                // Cost of add = 1
                double distance_add = matrix[i, (j - 1)] + 1;

                matrix[i, j] = Math.Min(distance_replace, 
                                    Math.Min(distance_add, distance_remove));
            }
        }

        return matrix[b1.Length, b2.Length] ;
    }
```

You see how it works here: http://ideone.com/RblFK