# How to find visual similarities between String in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently using Pytesseract to read image and extract usernames from it

Then I need to compare this string with a list of String I have (containing every possible username)

My problem is that sometime tesseract reads the word wrong, (example, poce instead of pocc) because e and c look similar

Therefore what I'm looking for is an algorithm (pre-existing?) that compare string based on visual similarity.

Example:

```
name_list = read_names_from_image(image)

for name in name_list:
    result = find_similar_name(name, username_list, threshold) #function I need
    if result:
        #DOSOMETHING
```

Hope this is clear

I looked a bit everywhere but I only found algorithm that check longuest subsequence or that kind of thing, but never visual similarity between characters. (fuzzywuzzy, difflib, levenstein distance...)

Comment: As per the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080958/ocr-weighted-levenshtein-distance referring to github: https://github.com/infoscout/weighted-levenshtein which shows how to weight characters for edit distance based on your own choice of weighting, eg. visual similarity

Comment: This seem to totally respond to my question, I searched but didn't stumble upon this question, thanks a lot